# Sort Array in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have to sort an array of objects based on 'x' value.

Object Name: Item
 Item has an int value "x"

for eg:

```
Array = {
  "Item", //x value 3 
  "Item", //x value 2 
  "Item", //x value 3 
  "Item", //x value 4
}
```

in the above array index value of object at index 0 and 2 are same. so preserve the order of Item value 3.

After sorting the array will return the value like this

```
 Array = {
      "A", //x value 2
      "A", //x value 3 // This object was at index 0 before sorting
      "A", //x value 3 // This object was at index 2 before sorting
      "A", //x value 4
    }
```

The above order is important.

how can sort it.

Comment: Your array doesn't contains plain string, correct? Are you using a custom object? In that case you should check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it

Comment: Would it be possible to provide the array initialization code in Objective-C? Or do you also want to know how to create an array that supports that kind of sorting?

Comment: I editted my question. please check it. if you are not clear. comment me.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what do you exactly mean, but there is  a cool method `sortedArrayUsingComparator`:

```
NSArray* sortedArray;
sortedArray = [originArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    // compare your objects as you wish!
}];
```

Comment: i updated my question. pls check it. i tried your answer but it's not working